# how to architect/organize a react application

Tags: reactjs

From a maintenance/architecture/performance perspective, when writing a react application, is it better to put all components in a super/parent component and bind it once to a page, or to have multiple mount nodes on the page for each piece of functionality?

My current approach is to have multiple mount nodes on the page so I can have a more flexible design. Basically like a bunch of 'component boxes' in different parts of the page, that way I can easily move an entire box to another part of the page and everything still works the same without being dependent on each other.

Is there a "best practice" for this (in terms of future maintenance), or has react not been around long enough to establish such a thing?

Comment: Flagged -- off-topic, asks for tutorial, tool, etc recommendations

Comment: @HunterStevens how am I asking for a tutorial or a tool? this is a legit question

Comment: In the title you ask "how to organize", and I see that as asking for a tutorial. I think something like this would be better to ask in a chat room.

Comment: @HunterStevens please suggest a title edit then because I'm not asking for a tutorial

Comment: I am not sure how to phrase this. I think it is better to ask in chat, because you are asking a yes/no answer (first paragraph is basically, choose A or B). Your third paragraph asks the "best practice" question which is not usually on-topic for SO (today's guidelines). I think you should ask this in chat since you have the rep to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common practice I've seen is a single mount point for a the main react `render`. This has a few advantages

- Keeps the HTML minimal and simple, this reduces potential confusion about what's handled by the DOM/HTML and what's handled by React/JSX.
- Reduces the interface boundary between the root HTML and React. Fewer places where `props` need to be passed from outside React.
- Simplifies the reasoning about what happens when. For example it can sometimes be tricky to determine when React applications are done rendering. Having multiple `render` operations makes this more difficult.